# Rendering native Android App with Phonegap

Tags: android, html, css

I'm developing an Android App with Phonegap. There is one thing wich gives me a headache and that is the rendering. For example the css borders, i use for every border a width of 1px but in my application some borders are thicker then others.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

I tried to change the metatag with this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; target-densityDpi=device-dpi; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=1; minimum-scale=1; user-scalable=0" />
```

In the android emulator it fixed my problem but on my HTC Sensation i still get the ugly rendering.

Comment: It's worth checking your what your code is using against caniuse.com. It's also a very good idea to test your code in a webkit based browser and on an Android device too. Weinre is a great tool to help you debug your DOM within the app: http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/

Comment: @AhmedNuaman I just tested on a browser on an Android device and that gives me the same problems also for other websites. Unfortunately it looks like a rendering problem in the Android browser.

Comment: What version of Android are you using? Did you check caniuse.com?

Comment: Android 4.0.3, yes I checked and there are no problems using the css I use for my App

Comment: And what if you run the HTML and CSS in the standard Android browser, how does it render then?

Comment: It renders the same as the App

Comment: Paste your CSS code and we'll take a look

Comment: Well, for example... I have a list with a bottom border. This border is 1px but in the browser it look like some borders in that list are thicker then others in the same list. The code: #invoiceTypeList ul li
{
 border-bottom:1px solid #CFD3D8;
 height:40px;
 line-height:40px;
 text-indent:15px;
}